# Can an Android app be used to set the phone password?

Tags: android, api, security

I had an idea for an android security app, but looking over the Device Administrator api documentation, I can't see if it's even possible.  I want the app to be able to set the password used to unlock the phone.  It would need to set the password without input or confirmation from the user.

Anyone know if it's even possible, and if so, is there any documentation for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found what I was looking for, it can be done per

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#resetPassword(java.lang.String, int)

public boolean resetPassword (String password, int flags)

Added in API level 8
Force a new device unlock password (the password needed to access the entire device, not for individual accounts) on the user. This takes effect immediately. The given password must be sufficient for the current password quality and length constraints as returned by getPasswordQuality(ComponentName) and getPasswordMinimumLength(ComponentName); if it does not meet these constraints, then it will be rejected and false returned. Note that the password may be a stronger quality (containing alphanumeric characters when the requested quality is only numeric), in which case the currently active quality will be increased to match.

The calling device admin must have requested USES_POLICY_RESET_PASSWORD to be able to call this method; if it has not, a security exception will be thrown.

Parameters
password    The new password for the user.
flags   May be 0 or RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY.
Returns
Returns true if the password was applied, or false if it is not acceptable for the current constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible at all, since every app runs in kind of a sandbox to forbid for example malware executing something like you mentioned.

Comment: The app would have to be given device administrator permissions. The device admin api lets you turn off the password entirely and can even remote wipe the phone. It's not a security risk, just whether they built that functionality into it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

There seems to be a way for an app to **ask** for a password:

> Set a password for the device
>   This code displays a user interface prompting the user to set a password:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, I'm not sure you can do this from within the app, silently without any user input. Also, Device Administration apps does not seem to be a normal apps and seem to be intended for corporations/institutions.